# Hartshorne Page 307, Proposition 3.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was reading the proof of the Proposition (3.1, IV) in [Hartshorne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hartshorne)'s Algebraic Geometry book.

Proposition: Let $D$ be a divisor on a curve $X$. Then:

(a) the complete linear system $\vert D \vert$ has no base points if and only if for every point $P\in X$, $$ \dim \vert D-P \vert = \dim \vert D \vert - 1;$$
(b) $D$ is very ample if and only if for every points $P, Q\in X$(including the case $P=Q$), $$ \dim \vert D-P-Q \vert = \dim \vert D \vert - 2.$$

In the proof, I could not understand the line in the proof which says that if $D$ satisfies the condition (b), then we have
$$ \dim \vert D-P \vert = \dim \vert D \vert - 1$$ for every $P\in X.$

(It may be silly question.)

I would be thankful if someone could elaborate this sentence.

Comment: I don’t have my copy of Hartshorne on me, but if you’re comfortable with the proof of (a) then just use the fact that very ample line bundles are base point free, and apply (a).

Comment: For any divisor $D$ and any point $P$ (with no condition), you always have an inequality, $\dim |D|-1\leq\dim |D-P|\leq \dim |D|$. Use this with (b) to deduce what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get this off the unanswered list while it's active.

As Mohan points out in the comments, for any divisor $D$ on a curve $C$ and any point $P\in C$, we have the inequality $$\dim |D|-1\leq \dim |D-P|\leq \dim |D|.$$ This comes from taking global sections of the short exact sequence of sheaves $$0\to\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)\to\mathcal{O}_C(D)\to k(P)\to 0,$$ which gives the half-exact sequence of vector spaces $$0\to H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) \to H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D)) \to k.$$ The second map has image either $0$ or $k$, and therefore either $\dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) = \dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D))$ or $\dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) = \dim H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D))-1$, respectively. After projectivizing, we get that $\dim |D-P|$ is either $\dim |D|$ or $\dim |D|-1$ and the claim is proven.

To use this to attack the statement you had trouble with, note that if $\dim |D-P-Q| = \dim |D|-2$ for all $P,Q$, then we must have $\dim |D-P|=\dim |D|-1$ for all $P$.